# jQuery functions act differently than their JavaScript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on automating a site and in console. When I am using
jQuery methods to change value of dropdown (hidden/generated values) it works perfectly fine, correctly mimics human behavior.

But when I am using JavaScript it's changing the value, but the next dropdown doesn't get activated.

The code I am using:

jQuery

```
$("#carMakeInput").val("BMW").change()
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("carMakeInput").value = "BMW";
document.getElementById("carMakeInput").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

Does jQuery do something extra?

Comment: It's not clear to me what difference in behavior you're describing.  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates both and describe specifically the difference you're seeing?

Comment: Go into [source code of jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/main/src) and dig it out what's actually happening

Comment: Exactly what's happening in your case I do not know, but in general jQuery is much older than many modern browser APIs, and they are definitely not always the same in functionality.

Comment: @Justinas that is certainly a possibility, but understanding jQuery behavior from its source code is beyond the abilities of the vast majority of competent JavaScript programmers. It's very compact code, having been developed over the course of almost 20 years now.

Comment: Basically "equivalent" is not really the right word to use; more like "similar". And those APIs like `.dispatchEvent()` are not part of JavaScript, they're part of web browsers.

Comment: @Pointy In particular, the code for the `trigger` method in jQuery is pretty complex, because it has to deal with internal jQuery events, native browser events, translating event names to event objects, etc.

Comment: Right, also it's most definitely not the case that when the W3C was codifying new APIs for the DOM that they followed the "make it just like jQuery" rule.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little snippet to test what you were saying. In my snippet, JS is activating and jquery not (I confirmed by commenting out the lines that fire the change event). So I think it's a question of how you add the listener

```js
document.getElementById("carMakeInput").addEventListener("change", function() {console.log("changed");});

$("#carMakeInput").val("BMW").change()

document.getElementById("carMakeInput").value = "BMW";
document.getElementById("carMakeInput").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="carMakeInput" />
```